# How to convert an array of objects to an array from classes?

Tags: arrays, typescript

How to convert an array of objects to an array from classes?
without a loop?

https://repl.it/repls/YellowSuperficialHexagons

```
export class Lead {
public value =  'val';

public constructor(      init?: Partial<Lead>      ) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
}

public printOk(){
  return this.value + ' ok';
}
}

let arr = [ {'value': '1'}, {'value': '2'} ]

let lead: Lead = new Lead(arr[0]);
console.log(lead.printOk());

const leads:Partial<Lead>[] = arr;

console.log(leads[0].value);

//console.log(leads[0].printOk()); //error
```

Answer (score 3):

One way or another, you'll need to call new Lead for each element of `arr`. Simplest way to do this would probably be with array.map:

```
let arr = [ {'value': '1'}, {'value': '2'} ];
const leads: Lead[] = arr.map(init => new Lead(init));
```